# own share button like facebook

Tags: jquery, share

I want to make my own share button , i mean not facebook share customize. i will give that code to our partners and they put them into their website and the users of them can click "PP SHARE" button and the link with description will be shared on my website.

```
    <div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/tr_TR/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=158857144273307";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
```

How can i make it ? Where i have to look ?

Thank you so much.

Comment: This it not a tutorial site or free developer hiring site. So you need to try something and ask when you stucked

Comment: Thanks Chamika ,  i will and then ask but i think , maybe there ar smo who made that before and can help me where i can start